# How to use data in fields from one node to create a new node of different content type?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have a content type called "*Submit a photo*" where anonymous users can upload a photo alongside with their name, email and short description. And I have another content type where an admin uploads images and publishes them as "*Looks*", and Looks are more complicated content type, with image tags, categories ...

Than I have a view which lists all of the submitted images so that an editor can pick and create new node "Look" using existing fields. But I'm looking for a way to somehow pre populate fields in that new content type with fields of "Submit a photo".

So editors can review all the images that are submitted by anonymous users. If they like one, they click “Add new Look” or something like that, which opens a new “Add Look” form using that image.

Should I look at nodereference or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Node_convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) module. From it's project page:

> adds a menu tab "Convert" on the node view page, i.e. node/1/convert, which gives the ability to convert the node from its current node type to another node type. The module provides the means to transfer all the field values of the current node type into fields on the destination node type, or discard them.

I'm using [Node_convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) already for long time, works great. It allows for implementing a lifecycle (or workflow?) to start from a node that is only just something like an idea (or suggestion, question, issue, abstract, etc). So that would be like your "Submit a photo" content type. When the node's content evolves (read: the more effort/details added to it), I convert its content type to finished products like (eg) a recipe, a redbook (already from my Drupal 6 days a few years ago). In your case it'd be the "Look" content type.

By combining it with an access module such as [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) (my preference) or [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) you can make it more restrictive to give access to it. E.g. public (anybody) to start from, then "authenticated", and in the end only for roles such as "subscribers", "students", etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, i tried it and looks fine, but im having issues making it work with my custom made dashboard, i tried with VBO but it cant convert straight away, instead it gives me offer to pick themplate but i have only one...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module like so:

- Event: after saving new node
- Conditions : content type
- Action : create new node of "look", fetch images from "sumbit a photo" ,  update the created node.